# Quova API anyone? it's a complete disaster, anyone knows better ip-geolocation-services?

Tags: ip-geolocation

i need a geolocation service and i wanted to try some of them before buying anything for my client.

i tried api.ipinfodb.com and is pretty good...
then i recently tried Quova APi, that as far as i remeber Quova was considered good...

well...i tried it and the result is really sloppy... the zipcode with ipinfodb.com was perfect, whereas Quova was quite distant...

also the XML of the first was good formatted, whereas Quova gives you all lowercase name..why? shouldn be the city name cpaitalize ? i know i can do it with php but with name syou have to be careful...sound sjust sloppy to me...

I wonder if the paid Quova service is the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually the product manager for Quova, so I hope I can help.  Sorry you're having problems with the API.

To answer your first question about the zip code, no vendor can be right 100% of the time, and there will always be individual cases where we are wrong and someone else is right, or we are right and someone else is wrong.  We do provide confidence factors to help you decide how confident we are in the assignments we make, which helps customers make better decisions about the data.  Our customers stay with us because they know that the overall quality of our data outperforms the other vendors they've tried.  If you respond with the actual IP addresses and ZIP codes that you think are wrong, I can have them investigated.

With regard to our data being all lowercase, we made that decision a long time ago to make the data predictable and to make comparisions with our data easier.  I know there are use cases where having the correct capitalization of place names would be valuable, and lowercasing strings is easy enough if you have to do that, so we're considering how to provide capitalized names without impacting current customers who might be relying on the data in its current format.  One thing you can do in the meantime is use the Lat/Long to lookup the place name with a service like geonames.org.

To answer your last question, yes, the data is also lowercase in the commercial service.

Comment: Hi Perry, ive been trying to reach Quova for ages, your sales email doesnt seem to have anyone in the other end and phone is not working also. Do you guys have something like maxmind where we can do geolocation based on a local db file or all queries need to go to your servers first? cheers

Comment: Sorry @Ricardo, I left Quova early this year, but you can go to [link](http://developer.quova.com/) where you can access the API and post questions on the forum if you don't get responses from email/phone.  Quova offers the data through either a public API or a local server that downloads the data and makes it available for local queries.  It's possible to get the raw data, but that tends to be much more expensive.

Comment: The updated link is actually https://ipintelligence.neustar.biz/portal/#documentation